# i moved wp-config.php outside of public html and this broke my website

Tags: security

I moved it back and the website started working again.
I tried moving wp-config to secure my wordpress site

here is what i did:

1. created another file `config.php`
2. downloaded `wp-config` and copied all the code in it to `config.php`
3. cleaned all the code in `wp-config.php` and wrote this:

```
<?php
include('domains/mydomain.com/conf/config.php');
```

i wrote my real domain name instead of mydomain.com

4. uploaded `config.php` to /domains/mydomain.com/conf
5. uploaded `wp-config.php` to /domains/mydomain.com/public_html

before moving `wp-config.php`, i modified .htaccess to forbid public access to `wp-config.php`

what did i do wrong while moving wp-config.php ? i also tried uploading `config.php` without conf folder, to /domains/mydomain.com/ but the result is the same.

is .htaccess method enough or i still need to move wp-config.php outside of the public folder?

Comment: there is a typo, i used slash in the real file

Comment: it's very likely the problem is the relative path you used in your `include` statement, but you don't need to do this, WordPress already looks up one folder if it can't find a `wp-config.php` so all you need to do is move the file up one and adjust the include at the bottom for `wp-settings.php` to match the subfolder. Note though that you'll need to tell us how it is broken to debug this properly though, PHP error messages from your PHP error log will be very useful

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand wp-settings.php part. could you please clarify what i need to do? also, how do i access that error log?